# How to design an unbounded Monte Carlo algorithm for SAT(Boolean Satisfiability Problem) problem?

Tags: algorithm, montecarlo, sat

I want the algorithm to be in polynomial time and the correct answer rate is 0.5 or more.
(True / false judgment is polynomial time)

All the methods I think of take exponential time(2^n).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How do you know it's even possible? The success rate will probably depend on the particular problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Anyway, cs.stackexchange.com is certainly a better place to ask this.

Comment: With a spec that loose, you can literally just flip a coin.

Comment: Crossposted https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/142538/472